# Drupal Schema.org Metatag

Tags: drupal-8, meta-tags

I have a problem displaying the json object, there are null attributes. When I add the name attribute for the first time it is displayed correctly but when I add a second telephone attribute for example, the name attribute takes the value null when displayed.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKkMC.png)

I tried even with version 3.0.1 (metatag schema) but I had the same problem. Do you have a solution, any ideas?